# Why does this generator not work in python

Tags: python

Why does `if` not work in the below generator

```
def mygen(m):
    n = 0
    if n < m:
        n = n + 1
        yield n

counter = mygen(5)

next(counter)
1
next(counter)
StopIteration
```

but `while` does?

```
def mygen(m):
    n = 0
    while n < m:
        n = n + 1
        yield n
```

Comment: are you comparing if to while? For loops are comparable to while loops.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop compares `n` and `m` repeatedly (until the condition is false) whereas the `if` statement compares them once and then finishes. The `if` statement is working, just not in the way you are expecting.